# Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError when doing Get Request to Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Do not know how to solve the problem below

I cannot get a response from Microsoft Graph API. API works with some other requests.
I was following instructions from these pages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet-app-only?tabs=aad but cannot make my own requests.

App permissions that are given and confirmed by admin:

- Application.Read.All
- Chat.Read.All
- Chat.ReadBasic.All
- Chat.ReadWrite.All
- Group.Read.All
- User.Read.All

I get ids of users with:

```cs
_ = _appClient ??
            throw new System.NullReferenceException("Graph has not been initialized for app-only auth");
var response = await _appClient.Users.GetAsync();
```

There are no exceptions, everything works (as I understand it must work).
And then try to get all the chats from Microft Teams of the user using his id:

```cs
var response = await _appClient.Users[id].Chats.GetAsync();
```

[Exception message and Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XexYz.png)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#error-handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what type of error it was with the help of ODataError class:

```cs
try
{
      var response = await _userClient.Me.Chats.GetAsync();
      return response;
}catch (ODataError er)
{
      Console.WriteLine(er.Error.Code);
      Console.WriteLine(er.Error.Message);
      return null;
}
```

Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

@SergioMartin, Yes, the exception is misleading, you need to check the InnerException why you got into this state. Catch the exception on the call and check the inner exception. It could be a different reason. Also check the token with

> https://jwt.ms/